# First Order Differential Equation Problem - Calorie intake

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**UPDATE**:  Thanks to Matthew for pointing out what to do next, this problem has been solved.

Thanks everyone for your time and effort.

I've been stuck on this DE problem for a few days now and was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.  I know the solution is $101$ days.

The daily calorie intake is taken to be a fixed quantity $C$ and is modelled by the DE.

$$\frac{dt}{dm} = \frac{1}{a(C-bm)}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are both constants.

A man is $90$kg.  If he were to take no calories for $14$ days, his mass would reduce by $20$%.  How long will it take him to reduce his mas by the same amount if he took $3/4$ of the calories required to keep his mass constant at $90$kg?

I'm missing something simple, but just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advanced.

So far I have the general solution to the DE as:

$$\int dt = \int\frac{1}{a(C-bm)} dm$$

$$t + K = - \frac{1}{ab} ln|C-bm| $$

$$-tab - Kab = ln|C-bm| $$

$$|C-bm| = e^{-tab} e^{-Kab}$$

$$C-bm = Ae^{-tab}$$ where $$A=\pm e^{-Kab}$$ and $K$ is an arbitrary constant.

Now, when $t=0$ $m=90$kg, so $A=C-90b$, therefore we now have

$$C-bm = (C-90b)e^{-tab}$$

Transposing

$$ bm= \frac{C-(C-90b)e^{-tab}}{b}$$

$$ m(t) = \frac{C+(90b-C)e^{-tab}}{b}$$

Next, $t=14$ , $m=72$ ($20$% reduction of $90$), $C=0$

$$72b = 90be^{-14ab}$$

$$\frac{72}{90} = e^{-14ab}$$

$$e^{14ab} = \frac{90}{72}$$

Thus

$$ab=\frac{\ln\frac{90}{72}}{14}$$

$$ab=\frac{1}{14}\ln\Big(\frac{5}{4}\Big)$$

$$ab=0.0159$$

So substituting $ab$ back into the equation

$$ m(t) = \frac{C+(90b-C)e^{-t0.0159}}{b}$$

So I have 3 unknows $C$ , $b$ and $t$. I can seem to extract the required information to solve for $t$.

The next part is where I get stuck.  I don't know how to implement the $3/4$ of the calories required in my formula.

Comment: where did you get stuck?, show us your work

Comment: I will add my workings in the original post.

Comment: Explicitly expressed his weight constantly reduces, when he is not eating.

$m=\frac{90be^{tab}+C}{b}$

Comment: Did you get the $\pm$ by taking a square root?

Comment: This is a separable differential equation. To solve this equation, you should multiply both sides by $(C - bm) \: dt$ then integrate. Have you verified your general solution to the DE?

Comment: this edit helped, if i were you i'd introduce a new variable to $e^{ab}$, maybe it helps

Comment: this new $m=\text{stuff and }e^{-t}$ finally checks out for the decreasing weight, which can be counterbalanced with the $+C$(calorie intake), feel free to use $|\pm A|$ as the $e^{-t}$ can only cause weight loss not weight gain (especially not on the negative side)

Comment: to get the answer to the final question you need to solve $m_{72}(t_{14})$ for $m$ (parametrically), then plug that into a general solution which has $\frac{3}{4}C$ in it and solve for $t$. Theoretically that should work.

Answer (score 1):

@Stephen you're right. I made an elementary integration error. Here is the correct solution.

The solution to the DE $\frac{dm}{dt}=a(C-bm)$ subject to the initial condition $m(0)=90$ is $$m(t)=\frac{C+(90b-C)e^{-abt}}{b}$$ If $C=0$ then $m(14)=72$ implies $ab=\frac{1}{14}\ln\Big(\frac{5}{4}\Big)$ which reduces our solution to $$m(t)=\frac{C+(90b-C)(0.8)^{t/14}}{b}$$The daily calorie intake which renders the mass of the individual constant is $C^{*}=bm_0$ where $m_0$ is the initial mass. In our scenario our person initially weighs $m_0=90 \text{kg}$ making $C^*=90b$. Replacing $C$ with $\frac{3}{4}C^*=\frac{135b}{2}$ in our solution gives $$m(t)=\frac{135}{2}+\frac{45}{2}(0.8)^{t/14}$$ Solving $m(t)=72$ for $t$ yields $t\approx 101$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I can't understand how you solved the DE.  Can you please expand on that part of the solution.  I was wondering why there is only $at$ in the power of e.

Comment: I wrote your DE as $\frac{dm}{C-bm}=adt$

Comment: I did Matthew, but what happened to the $-\frac{1}{b}$ after you antidifferentiate on the LHS?  I thought you would get $ -\frac{1}{b}ln|C-bm|$

Comment: @Stephen you're correct. I made an integration mistake. The solution has been updated.

Comment: Thanks Mathew.  That helps me A LOT.  The $\frac{3}{4}C^*=\frac{135b}{2}$ was the part of the problem that helped me.   VERY much appreciated.